# iMacro extracting data to csv file for not found elements

Tags: csv, extract, imacros

I have following iim file:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=http://example.com

SET !DATASOURCE csv_example.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2

' it will loop trought 1000 records
SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
' input fields from csv file
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ex1 ATTR=NAME:im1 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:ex1 ATTR=NAME:im2 CONTENT={{!COL2}}
' submit form
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:ex1 ATTR=TXT:Submit

' wait while ajax request finish
WAIT SECONDS=60

' start extract to csv file

' first results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input2 EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT "1"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:apple1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:hp1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:lg1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:canon1 EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\iMacros FILE=Example_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv


' second results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input2 EXTRACT=TXT

ADD !EXTRACT "2"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:apple2 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:hp2 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:lg2 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:canon2 EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\iMacros FILE=Example_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv

' third results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input2 EXTRACT=TXT

ADD !EXTRACT "3"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:apple3 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:hp3 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:lg3 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:canon3 EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\iMacros FILE=Example_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv
```

But the problem is that, when for example

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:apple3 EXTRACT=TXT

**Is not found in result page, it is not exported to csv file as "", but at once exports next element text**

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:hp3 EXTRACT=TXT,

And due to that there are not 7 columns in that row, but for example 6, and I cannot check what value is empty, because they exports as comma delimited.

As far as I know, iMacros don't support if else statements, so I cannot check if it empty or not.

Comment: What 'iMacros' and browser do you use?

Comment: @Shugar, Sorry, forgot mention it, I'm using last version of addon iMacros for Firefox.

Comment: Hey @AlexIL, I have just run into a brick wall with imacros. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532248/imacros-submitting-textarea-form-enter-key-maybe if you happen to know the answer you'd be my savior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement the idea like this:

```
'...

' third results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input1 EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:input2 EXTRACT=TXT

ADD !EXTRACT "3"
SET myExtract {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:apple3 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
ADD myExtract [EXTRACT]{{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:hp3 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
ADD myExtract [EXTRACT]{{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL 

'...

SET !EXTRACT {{myExtract}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\iMacros FILE=Example_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv
```

Alternatively, I advise you to use 'iMacros for Firefox' v.8.9.7 (with disabled autoupdates) and your own macro. This older version works differently from what you described above.

Comment: big thanks for your answer! Just install older version helped resolve this problem. This confirms once again that new does not mean better. :) Thank you!

Comment: :) FYI: 'iMacros for Chrome' seems to have the same problem, therefore my suggested code may be useful for Chrome users as well.

Comment: Hey man, I have just run into a brick wall with imacros. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532248/imacros-submitting-textarea-form-enter-key-maybe if you happen to know the answer you'd be my savior